# open another page inside fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using `jquery 1.9` & `fancybox 2.1.5`
I want to open another `.aspx` page inside fancybox. i did not want write `<a>` tag on my `aspx`

Instead am passing page address as parameter to fancybox using `href` tag.

but still it is not opening. it doesnt give any error in `console.log`

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yhfe0g70/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the type to "iframe".
Also, some sites, like google.com block being embeded: `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

```
$.fancybox({
    href: 'http://www.xkcd.com',
    type: "iframe"
});
```